# The meaning of a sentence including the verb "bid"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is an example that Longman dictionary provided for the verb "bid":

> What am I bid for lot 227? Shall we start at $500?

I've red the definition of the word "bid". Yet, I need to make sure that I'm not mistaken. My question is that: can we say the meaning of "**what am I bid for**" is close to "**what is the base price I am supposed to pay**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an auction: a "lot", a set of goods, is offered for sale to many interested buyers, who are all present.  A *bid* here is an *offer*, and the question *What am I bid?* means *How much am I offered?* for the lot. Successive bidders (including the original bidder) "top" the preceding bid—offer a higher amount. This continues, with each bid higher than the previous bid, until someone offers an amount which no one is willing to top. This high bidder receives the lot at that price. The *high* bid gets the goods offered.

*Start at $500* means the auctioneer—the person conducting the auction—is suggesting $500 as a reasonable starting point. In some cases, this means the seller will not sell at any lower price; in other cases,  bidders are free to offer a smaller amount.

In ordinary business a different sort of bidding is employed. A particular contract for goods or services is "put out to bid" by the purchaser, and interested vendors are invited to name the price—the *bid*—for which they are willing to sell the specified goods or services. The sale is conducted by mail, so bidders are typically unaware of their competitors' bids. In this case the *low* bid gets the contract.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answers are always great. Not only I get what I'm looking for, but also I learn something new regarding that topic.

Comment: Note there are many variations. When there is one seller and many potential buyers, the seller normally wants the highest price, so the high bid wins. When there is one buyer and many potential sellers, the buyer wants the lowest price, so the low bid wins. In either case, there can be "open bidding" where everyone knows what others bid, and "closed", "sealed", or "secret" bidding, where people are not allowed to know others bids.